# Directus ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, directus

I'm trying to connect the CMS "Directus". But ervery time i try to do so i get this error

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:66:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:61:12)
    at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\directus\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:247:39)
```

I can't really figure out waht the problem is.

Comment: The default root user for XAMPP has no password set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the default user password you will need to edit the `config.inc.php` file located in `XAMMP/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

From

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

To

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

Before you save the file, you will need update the password for root@localhost
[image]